# PHP output image issues

Tags: php, image, header, mime

```
if (file_exists($path)) {

    $fileContent = id3_getImage($path); 
    $fileMime = id3_getMimeOfImage($path); // is set to image/jpeg

    if ($fileMime != "") {
        header('Content-Type: '.$fileMime);
        print($fileContent);
        die;
    }
}
```

So the above code does not work in the browser, however when I make a image with image

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring($fileContent);
imagejpeg($img, 'test.jpg');die;
```

the image is created and I can view it on my computer. So I have no clue what I am doing wrong :(

*Could it be a setting in the apache conf? I honestly have no clue on this one

Comment: I need to dynamically create the images, so it's not really an option to create the image and then redirect them to that path. Anyway, it should work this way though

Comment: just use `imagejpeg($img, NULL);`

Comment: Please explain id3_getImage() and id3_getMimeOfImage() - these are not valid operators.

Comment: It's a custom function, using the class getid3 (http://getid3.sourceforge.net/), I'm sure the content of that $var is correct since using imagejpeg makes a valid image.

Comment: Because I am retreiving the cover from a music file to display it on a site.

Comment: This was an important part of missing information. =))

Comment: Sorry, I thought it wasn't that relevant :)

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($img);
```

You need send header before. But if you want to create the image and show, you need create, and read this for the browser.

```
readfile($filename);
```

You can read the man here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, you do not need to use readfile($filename) as the content of the file is the same as in the $var and they both print it to the browser

Comment: You need to use `imagejpeg($img, 'test.jpg');` and use `readfile('test.jpg');`

Comment: I wasn't sure about that as I thought it would have the same output, but I've tested it anyway, with no result :(

Comment: If you are use by filename file, you don't send the result on the browser. That's just for save file. But if you want to save the file and print on the browser, you need to use with `readfile()`. If you just want to print the image on the browser, you can use with `imagejpeg()` without `$filename` var.

Comment: I do not want to save the image, and using imagejpeg isn't working. That's why I have no clue what the error is causing, because it should in fact work.

Answer (score 0):

I use smartReadFile.php from Google Groups to display any type of file.

https://jplayer.googlegroups.com/attach/f308294ddea52f6c/smartReadFile.php?view=1&part=4

It's really smart. =)

```
<?php 

require "smartReadFile.php";

$dir = 'images/';
$filename = 'someimage' . '.jpg';
$location = $dir.$filename;

smartReadFile($location, $filename);

?>
```

Comment: Using that and still doesn't work, I think I need to change somthing in my apache conf. Since the URL doesn't have an extension .jpg, actually it doesn't have any extension. It's just /cover/

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me when reading from DB

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring([path/DBfiels]);  
header('content-type: image/jpeg');  
imagejpeg($image); 
imagedestroy($image);
```